# Is there a way to export an AWS RDS MySQL database without having to export it to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, export, amazon-rds

I am trying to use my client's RDS MySQL instance as the data dump for the development database on my local machine so that I can finally start working on his project. I am only seeing an option to export a snapshot to S3 but I don't have access to S3, so I can't even list the buckets to see where to store it. Is there any other way to do this in the AWS console... like a button somewhere that says "export" which exports the database directly to my local machine?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: Oh, damn. That's unfortunate. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Why not do a simple `mysqldump`? Since you said it's a dev db, I assume it doesn't have much data in it.

Comment: @jellycsc Yea, I was thinking of doing that actually. However, since it's in a private subnet and isn't publicly accessible wouldn't that disable me from connecting to it from my terminal? I can SSH into the EC2 but when I tried to connect to the database from the application prior to making a local database, I was getting an error. I am not very experienced with AWS, so maybe I'm wrong here. At the moment I am trying to just get my client to set me up with a policy in IAM that allows me to access S3 so that I can just export the snapshot and download it from there.

Comment: Is your database and EC2 instance both in the same VPC and have the same subnet? @NicholasGati

Comment: You are getting dumped on your laptop? @NicholasGati